# Raspberry Pi boot script duplicating

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alexa-skills-kit, autostart

I am trying to run a few scripts at each boot of the raspberry pi.  I have been able to verify that when they are not configured to start automatically, I can run them, and they all work exactly as intended (and in only one instance).  I have tried quite a few methods of autostarting these scripts, and I have found that using a desktop entry in .config/autostart directory to be my preferred way of doing it.  I have also tried editing rc.local, crontab, systemd, and entries in .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart with no more success.

The issue is that when I have the scripts running at boot, there is a duplicate of the script running (I have it set to open a new instance of LXterminal, though there are not duplicates of the terminal).  The script runs at boot just fine, but I am cannot figure out why there seems to be a "ghost" version of the script too.  I have the autostart commands set to write to log files that show that the scripts are running more than once.  I have also tried this on a fresh raspbian install.  Could someone help me figure this out?  I'm at a loss on what my issue is. This is for use of Amazon Alexa.

This is what I have in /home/pi/.config/autostart/AlexaBoot.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AlexaBoot
Exec=lxterminal -e "/bin/bash /home/pi/Desktop/alexa_boot.sh"
Type=Application
```

I can post what I have in the autostarted script if necessary.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for this.  My solution is outlined on a similar [Github issue](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/issues/726#issuecomment-299055176), hopefully this is able to help someone with the same issue.